# Using reactive values in linear prediction (ShinyApp)

Tags: r, machine-learning, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm working on a calculator that can predict post-college income for a machine learning class. I'm having some trouble getting the calculator to work. I get this error:

```
Error in output$predincome <- renderText(output()) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

When I run the code and my ShinyApp crashes.

Here is my code:

```
data <- read_rds("x3.rds")
model <- read_rds("fixed.rds")
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
    
    br(),
    
    navbarPage("Postgraduate Income Calculator",
        selectInput("tier", "College Attended:", levels(data$tier))),
        numericInput("par_mean", "Parent Income:", 0),
        numericInput("cohort", "Year Born:", 0),
        textOutput("predincome")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

df <- reactive(data.frame("cohort" = input$cohort, "tier" = input$tier, "par_mean" = input$par_mean))

  output <- reactive({predict(model, df())})
  output$predincome <- renderText(output())

}
```

In case it's helpful here is my model:

```
lm(k_mean ~ par_mean + factor(tier) + factor(cohort), data = training, weights = count)
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample data to test your code?

Comment: Name your reactive something other than `output`. It's clashing with the shiny `output` object.

Comment: Thank you!! The app is no longer crashing, no longer getting errors which is great. For some reason though the text output isn't working (nothing comes up when I populate the fields) do you know why that might be?

Comment: @msr_003 I'll go ahead and do that!

Comment: @MikkoMarttila sorry I'm new to posting on the site (I commented but forgot to tag you) but that removed the code error and the shiny app is no longer crashing, so thank you! This was a great help! The output is not working though (there is no output, it's blank) do you know why that might be?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I added a sidebar panel and when I removed that the text output worked. Not sure why that is but thank you so much for your help again I really appreciate it!